# Image slider doesn't show my images properly before they're cached

Tags: javascript, meteor, slick.js

**EDIT:** [MeteorPad demo here.](http://meteorpad.com/pad/zbfFqkvEKNgdXfKi9/Leaderboard) (The slider should work but it shouldn't show the first image, only a sliver of it. But the bug only shows sometimes (and primarily on Safari or everything that isn't Chrome), so beware).

**EDIT:** The bug is that the first image in the slider is not displayed properly, only the very top of it, until you swipe or click the next/prev button. This bug only turns up if you load the images from a database source, not when you use the slider "normally".

I'm using [Ken Wheeler's Slick slider](https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick), and while it's the best I've found it comes with a pretty nasty bug when I want to load images in an `each` loop in that it only shows the top of them until I press either the next/prev buttons or drag to the next image.

My collection has the following field:

```
"galleryImages": [
    {
      "name": "picture1",
      "position": "first"
    },
    {
      "name": "picture2",
      "position": "second",
    },
    {
      "name": "picture3",
      "position": "last"
    }
]
```

I use `gallery` as the `slick` container:

```
<div class="gallery">
  {{#each galleryImages}}
    <div>{{> Images}}</div>
  {{/each}}
</div>

<template name="Images">
  <img src="{{imageUrlMaker name}}" alt="{{name}}">
</template>
```

The `imageUrlMaker` just creates the correct url to fetch them at, not an issue.

And when `Images` is rendered I initialize the slider:

```
Template.Images.onRendered(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('.gallery').slick({
            arrows: true,
            dots: true,
            infinite: true,
            mobileFirst: true,
            adaptiveHeight: true
        })
    }, 100)
})
```

The reason for the `setTimeout` is that I find it erases some of the times the slider initializes before the images are loaded (for some reason).

As I said, the first time I visit a page that has images, they won't show (only the top) until they are dragged or the prev/next buttons are clicked. Or I could reload the page and everything will work.

Can anyone think of a workaround or fix, maybe using `position: "last"` in some clever way? Can anyone figure out *why* this bug shows?

Comment: It will be easier to help if you add a JSFiddle

Comment: @AsafDavid How exactly do you want me to make a fiddle of this when it depends on a lot of Meteor code?

Comment: Hello Yeats, have you found a solution? If not, I think I know what could cause this.

Comment: @BishopBarber Nope, haven't figured it out yet.

Comment: Read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30143116/2835243). I was about to write an answer, but saw that this one already existed, which answers pretty much to your question. If you have any questions, do not hesitate to ask.

Comment: @BishopBarber You got my hopes up, but I've already followed the directions in that post earlier and it's exactly how I have things set up.

Comment: @Yeats I'm sorry for giving you false hopes, I didn't realize you had the same thing. Don't worry though, we'll find the culprit. I created a [demo](http://meteorpad.com/pad/uHPQYwTEzXyQ6ap2h/Slick) out of your problem. But I'm afraid I'm not exactly sure what your problem is. Do you get the same thing as in my demo? If yes, can you tell me the anomaly? If no, are you able to find the mistake in your code?

Comment: @BishopBarber Not sure, the bug only shows up sometimes so it's hard to troubleshoot. Cn't make it show up in your version, but the only difference is that you loaded it from a CDN while I have been using a Meteor package. I tried the CDN way in my actual app and the bug showed again, so I guess that wasn't it. Here's my Meteorpad version whre the bug shows up a lot more consistently: http://meteorpad.com/pad/zbfFqkvEKNgdXfKi9/Leaderboard

Comment: @Yeats After playing a bit with it, it looks like some sort of bug to me. What fixed it is adding a css rule to your images: `.gallery img` and setting the width and height. There's probably a reason, but I don't have time to investigate further. For now you have a workaround.

Answer (score 2):

First of all: you're initializing your entire slick slider on every image render, if I'm not mistaken.
Therefore it would be better to run `$('.gallery').slick` within `Template.Gallery.onRendered()` rather than `Template.Images.onRendered()`.

The issue is that you'll have to wait for (1) the Gallery Collection to be ready and (2) the images to be loaded.

The only thing I could come up with to address both of those issues is to access the collection within a `Meteor.autorun()` and make sure the first image is loaded by the browser using an `Image.onload`:

```
Template.Gallery.onRendered(function() {

  Meteor.autorun(function() {
    var firstImage = Gallery.findOne();
    if (firstImage) {
      var img = new Image();
      img.onload = function() {
            $('.gallery').slick({
                infinite: true,
                mobileFirst: true,
                adaptiveHeight: true
            });
      }
      img.src = firstImage.url;
    }
  });
})
```

I see two possible issues with this approach, though:

- Since the slick initializer is within a `Meteor.autorun()` it will run every time there's a change on the Gallery datasource. This may or may not be a problem.
- It's not actually guaranteed that the images are rendered by the time the slick initializer runs. You may want to encapsulate some of the code within a `Meteor.timeout()` with a timeout of `0` just to make sure it runs within the next cycle. By then the renderer should have reacted to the datasource and created all the image DOM nodes.

Hope this helps in any way.

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30143116/2835243) for the reason for initiliazing in `Images`. I'll experiment with your other suggestion.

Comment: I see, thank you. Though I think your problem remains that the slider is initialized before the image is fully loaded, therefore the browser doesn't know its dimensions yet. I suggest to wait on `Image.onload` anyway.