# Meteor and getting carousel to render dynamically with #each

Tags: meteor, carousel, each, slick.js

Like slick.  Struggling to get it working w/ dynamic dataset from Meteor.  Problem that I now have, when opening prior instances of an item I'm left w/ ghost blank slides from priorly selected.  If I open an item that has 15 images, close it and select another w/ 1 - I have 14 blank slide.  Also, if I had clicked through the 15, say to the 7th slide, when I open the new item w/ 1 I'm still pointed at slide 7, which is blank, and need to click 6 slides to the left to actually see an image.

It would seem to me that I need to somehow reset the slick control?  I'm just not sure where of how to do it.

Followed instructions here: [Image slider doesn't show my images properly before they're cached](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31491694/image-slider-doesnt-show-my-images-properly-before-theyre-cached) to get up and running.

parent template

```
<div class="col-md-7">
  <div class="gallery">
    {{#each galleryImages}}
      {{> slickItem}}
    {{/each}}
  </div>
</div>
```

slick template

```
<template name="slickItem">
    <img class="slick-image" src="{{href}}">
</template>
```

I've played around w/ a few different options on the slick render.

```
 Template.slickItem.onRendered(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('.gallery').slick({
            arrows: true,
            dots: false,
            autoplay: false,
            infinite: true,
            mobileFirst: true,
            adaptiveHeight: true
        })
    }, 100);
});
```

Comment: about to give up on Slick.  From a meteor standpoint, I can't believe there isn't more documentation around this.  I mean - who is using a carousel and NOT feeding it with an #each?

Comment: Here is the sub template w/ onRendered approach - which I've found to be unstable and buggy:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30140232/meteor-with-iron-router-cant-get-slick-carousel-working

Comment: and what seems like should be the right answer, or heading toward it:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25354070/meteor-call-function-after-template-is-rendered-with-data

Comment: for those w/ similar issue - starting to zero in on this being a Meteor issue w/ handling of onRendered.  I've posed the question to the Meteor community directly: https://forums.meteor.com/t/does-onrendered-work-in-a-useful-way/14587

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working with friend Patrick Lewis we worked out the following - done now in React versus Blaze.

Carousel = React.createClass({

```
getInitialState: function() {
    return {
          carousel : null
    }
},

componentDidMount() {

    console.log("componentDidMount");

    this.setState({
        // carousel: $('#maveletCarousel')
        carousel: $(this.props.id)
    }, function() {
        console.log("carousel: componentDidMount", this.state);
        this.state.carousel.carousel();
    });
},

initCarousel: function() {

    // $('#maveletCarousel').carousel();

    // Initialize the carousel
    if( this.state.carousel ) {
        this.state.carousel.carousel({
            interval : 2000
        });
    }

},

render() {

    var hrefId = "#" + this.props.id;

    // <li data-target={hrefId} key={ index } data-slide-to={ index } className={ indicatorClass }></li>

    return (

      <div id={this.props.id} className="carousel slide">

          <ol className="carousel-indicators">
              {
                  this.props.slides.map((slide, index) => {
                      return (
                          <li data-target={hrefId} key={ index } data-slide-to={ index }></li>
                      );
                  })
              }
          </ol>

          <div className="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
              {
                  this.props.slides.map((slide, index) => {
                      return (
                          slide && <Slide slide={ slide } key={ index } index={ index } initCarousel={ this.initCarousel }/>
                      );
                  })
              }
          </div>

          <a className="left carousel-control" href={ hrefId } role="button" data-slide="prev">
              <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
              <span className="sr-only">Previous</span>
          </a>
          <a className="right carousel-control" href={ hrefId } role="button" data-slide="next">
              <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
              <span className="sr-only">Next</span>
          </a>

      </div>

    );
}
```

});

Slide = React.createClass({

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.props.initCarousel();
},

render() {

    var isActive = 'item'
    if( this.props.index === 0 ) {
        isActive = 'item active'
    }

    return (

        <div className={ isActive }>
            <img src={this.props.slide.href}></img>
        </div>

    )
}
```

})

Comment: Did you find a Blaze soln?