# How to initialize a jQuery object once the layout has rendered?

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

I would like to define a few variables that I use to scope my jQuery selectors later on right after my app layout has been rendered.

I tried to define them with:

```
Meteor.startup(function () { /* Define variables */ })
```

But it did not work, the objects were empty

Here is how I declare my application layout :

```
Router.configure({
  layoutTemplate: 'layout'
});
```

Here is the layout itself :

```
<template name="layout">
  <div id="page_container">
    <header id="page_header">
    </header>

    <div id="page_content">
      {{> yield}}
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Here are the variables I am willing to declare :

```
  L.BODY = $("body");
  L.PC   = $("#page_content", L.BODY);
```

The declaration itself works fine, but `L.BODY` show the body of my application is still empty by the time I try to declare those variables.

How can I define jQuery objects once the layout of my application has rendered?

Comment: I hadn't realized `layout` was treated just as another template then. 
Many thanks for your help!

Comment: This question and my answer could be of interest if you need to guarantee that DOM elements are present before doing any JQuery stuff. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32461639/how-to-execute-a-callback-after-an-each-is-done/32470003

Comment: @KassymDorsel Yep, it's pretty close but was on a different topic (iterations of `#each`), it does not apply very well here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`layout` is just another template. jQuery needs the DOM element to exist to create an object out of it.

From there the [`onRendered` callback](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_onRendered) is the way to go:

```
Template.layout.onRendered(function() {
  L.BODY = $('body');
  L.PC   = $('#page_content', L.BODY);
});
```