# Running Sortable in Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, rubaxa-sortable

First, I'm brand new to meteor/node, so please be gentle.

I'm trying to run https://github.com/RubaXa/Sortable but I can't get any of the samples to run locally.

http://jsbin.com/xizeh/2/edit?html,js,output being one suck example app that I can't get to work.  It results in this:

```
W20151202-10:36:50.714(-6)? (STDERR) 
W20151202-10:36:50.714(-6)? (STDERR) ~/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.1b51q9m++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:245
W20151202-10:36:50.714(-6)? (STDERR)                        throw(ex);
W20151202-10:36:50.714(-6)? (STDERR)                              ^
W20151202-10:36:50.717(-6)? (STDERR) ReferenceError: sortTrue is not defined
W20151202-10:36:50.717(-6)? (STDERR)     at hello.js:2:17
W20151202-10:36:50.717(-6)? (STDERR)     at ~/IdeaProjects/meteor_test_project/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/app/hello.js:22:4
W20151202-10:36:50.717(-6)? (STDERR)     at ~/IdeaProjects/meteor_test_project/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:242:10
W20151202-10:36:50.718(-6)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (native)
W20151202-10:36:50.718(-6)? (STDERR)     at Function._.each._.forEach (~/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.1b51q9m++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
W20151202-10:36:50.718(-6)? (STDERR)     at ~/IdeaProjects/meteor_test_project/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:137:5
=> Exited with code: 8
```

I've tried adding

```
var sortTrue = document.getElementById("sortTrue");
var sortFalse = document.getElementById("sortFalse");
```

only to get `ReferenceError: document is not defined` which I think happens because the javascript is ran prior to the document being loaded.  So, I tried wrapping it in `if (Meteor.isClient)` at which point the page load, but the elements wont move/sort.  The console shows this error:

```
Uncaught Sortable: `el` must be HTMLElement, and not [object Null]
    Sortable @ rubaxa_sortable.js:216
    Sortable.create @ rubaxa_sortable.js:1281
    (anonymous function) @ hello.js:15
    (anonymous function) @ hello.js:28
```

Seems to me that the meteor framework itself is having a problem - but I've been able to get all other sample apps to work (e.g. the one at https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/creating-an-app runs perfectly)

Note that I've tried a ton of different Sortable examples, all with the same results.  It's not this single app.

Comment: The `ReferenceError` was caused by your client code being run on the server, which you solved by wrapping it in `Meteor.isClient` (it has nothing to do with the DOM loading or not). What does make the value `null` is indeed that the code is executed before any rendering takes place. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32550273/4174897) might be a duplicate, please check.

Comment: I was able to get it working based on this, thank you.  I'll reply to my own question with the corrected script in case others encounter the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Based on Kyll's comment on my question I was able to get the linked example working with 
Script (modified):

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
    Template.body.onRendered(function(){
    // sort: true
        Sortable.create(sortTrue, {
            group: "sorting",
            sort: true
        });

    // sort: false
        Sortable.create(sortFalse, {
            group: "sorting",
            sort: false
        });
    })

}
```

Meteor HTML:

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>


  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>


  <!-- Latest Sortable -->
  <script src="http://rubaxa.github.io/Sortable/Sortable.js"></script>


  <!-- sort: true -->
  <div id="sortTrue" class="list-group">
    <div class="list-group-item">foo</div>
    <div class="list-group-item">bar</div>
    <div class="list-group-item">baz</div>
  </div>


  <!-- sort: false -->
  <div id="sortFalse" class="list-group">
    <div class="list-group-item">qux</div>
    <div class="list-group-item">quux</div>
  </div>


</body>
```

Note here that the first argument of the Sortable.create() function is the `id` of the `<div>` node which encapsulates the list which you want to make sortable.

CSS:

```
body {
  padding: 20px;
}

.list-group-item {
  cursor: move;
  cursor: -webkit-grabbing;
}
```

You also have to run `meteor add rubaxa:sortable` in the project workspace, and then add `rubaxa:sortable` to `<projectDIr>/.meteor/packages`

Comment: What are `sortTrue` and `sortFalse`?

Comment: They are the div ids from the linked sample application. 
e.g. 

<div id="sortTrue" class="list-group"><div class=[...]></div>

Comment: I think it would be better if you showed the whole code in your answer, including how you generated those variables.

Comment: Done.  Let me know if there's anything more I could do to clarify this.

Comment: Well, if the HTML code is needed to answer, it should be posted in the question itself. Same for the CSS, if needed. I think there was a misunderstanding: You have written `sortTrue` and `sortFalse` as _variables_, not as Strings (with quotes), so I thought you were getting the elements and assigning them to variables prior to using them!

Comment: The HTML didn't need to change - only the javascript.  I left that out of the original question, and relied on the linked sample app to provide, for brevity.  The use of the IDs as variables is from the example app.