# Issue embedding jquery menu to my MeteorJS application

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

I am trying to use a [jquery menu](https://jqueryui.com/menu/) in my MeteorJs application. But I'm kind of having an issue.

This is my folder structure and the code.

```html
<template name="menu">
  <div class="container">
  <nav id="bt-menu" class="bt-menu">
   <a href="#" class="bt-menu-trigger"><span>Menu</span></a>
   <ul>
    <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Clients</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
   </ul>
   <ul>
    <li><a href="http://www.twitter.com/codrops" class="bt-icon icon-twitter">Twitter</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://plus.google.com/101095823814290637419" class="bt-icon icon-gplus">Google+</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.facebook.com/pages/Codrops/159107397912" class="bt-icon icon-facebook">Facebook</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://github.com/codrops" class="bt-icon icon-github">icon-github</a></li>
   </ul>
 </nav>
</div>
</template>
```

This is how my main HTML file look like.

```html
<head>
  <title>TA3-Blog</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>
  <header class="codrops-header">
    {{>menu}}
  </header>
  {{renderPage}}
</body>
```

And here's the console error.

[image]

Comment: What's your `borderMenu.js` code ? Although based on the error I would guess that the DOM element you are calling it on doesn't exist yet. Have you looked at `onRendered()` yet ? Otherwise this answer may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32470003/991805

Comment: Could you also provide the code with the proper formatting? That way I can copy/paste it and use ***my*** colouration which is obviously the best that ever existed. Same goes for the errors please.

Comment: I have added the menu code and here's my borderMenu.js - http://pastebin.com/HXtGwu7R#

Comment: oh, ok. In that case where do you call the `borderMenu` init function ? You will want to do that in `Template.menu.onRendered(...)`