# Running JQUERY Scripts after DOM is loaded in Meteor js?

Tags: jquery, meteor, meteor-blaze, meteorite, flow-router

I want a jQuery script to load after all `DOM` elements are loaded. I tried to run through `Template.Mytemplare.onRendered();` But that is not solving my problem, because DOM is not ready Yet. Also I am using Flow-router not Iron Router So I can not use Iron Router's `onAfterAction` hook or template's rendered callback? I also used subscriptions so I load DOM if subscription is ready `Template.subscriptionReady`. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you already tried to use jQuery's `$(document).ready(function() { ... });`?

Comment: It's hard to know what to suggest without more details. Have a look at the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34777586/template-subscriptionsready-disables-onrendered-functionality) and see if that helps.

Comment: yes! I have used  $(document).ready(function() { ... }); But didn't work

Comment: Is it possible you're making an API call? maybe try the jquery `$.ajaxComplete` method... ?

Answer (score 0):

You could combine onRendered and jQuery's ready function:

```
Template.Mytemplate.onRendered(function() {
  $(function() {
      // your code goes here
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do it in Meteor now is with the below:

```
Template.MyTemplate.onRendered(function(){
    Tracker.afterFlush(function(){
        // run code in here
    });
});
```

Using afterFlush runs the code when the DOM has actually finished loading. You will need the Meteor "tracker" package, which is an official plugin.

Answer (score -1):

The Problem is that when `Template.myTemplate.onRendered();` is executed , the subscription is not ready yet , So DOM is not ready yet. as I have used `Template.subscriptionsReady` check before loading DOM. So There is a callback-function called  `OnReady()` when subscribing. it will go like this :
`Meteor.subscribe("somePublication", {onReady: function(){//code to perform after //subscription is ready goes here }})`

Comment: So basically the problem came from another part of the code you have not shared in your question, due to reasons you have not disclosed in your question? Also, subscriptions being ready have _nothing_ to do with the DOM!